Doubt regarding Riemann Integrable problems
I was trying to learn Riemann integration. So after that I wanted to practice some questions and got this.
Given a function, $f(x) = \sin{x}\  \ \text{if}\  \ x = \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x) = \cos{x} \  \text{ otherwise} $.
Check if it is integrable.
Now I was reading the solution and found that they have written "Note that f has only finite discontinuities in $[\frac{1}{N}, 1]$ .Hence integrable in $[\frac{1}{N}, 1]$". I have found this in a lot of similar problems but couldn't figure out the reason. Can anyone tell me how it works?
I am finding difficulty with the part where there are only a finite discontinuities in the interval. I don't understand the logic behind it.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Intuition:
Take a rectangle with length L and breadth B, now imagine in this rectangle, I drew two vertical lines at length B/3 and 2B/3, creating a rectangle of length L and breadth B/3 inside the bigger rectangle. The area of the Big rectangle is LB, the area of the middle rectangle is LB/3, and the area of the remaining portion is LB - LB/3 = 2LB/3.
Now imagine I keep shrinking the middle rectangle by reducing it's breadth, that will make the area of the remaining rectangle grow bigger and bigger, and if we shrink it so much that it is almost a line, then the area of the remaining rectangle will be same as the bigger rectangle.
So if I remove a line from the rectangle, it doesn't affect the overall area of rectangle.
So if I have finite discontinuities in a function, it doesn't affect the area below the function. It is same as removing finite number of lines from a planar region.
The above is not a rigorous proof. You can find the rigorous proof in Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin.

In fact, the function is Riemann integrable when the measure of the discontinuities is zero. You can simply interpret it that:
$$
\forall  ~\varepsilon >0, ~\exists[a_i,b_i]~, ~\sum_i|b_i-a_i|<\varepsilon
$$
and the series of intervals is countable and cover all discontinuities.
Maybe you should turn to "Lebesgue integrability criterion" for more information.
